# Unable to connect py2neo v3 with neo4j 3.4.1

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I have been trying to connect to my local neo4j server using py2neo v3 and neo4j version 3.4.1.

The commands I used are:-

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graphURL='http://localhost:7474/db/data/'
graphUser = "neo4j"
graphPassphrase = "XXXX"

graph=Graph(graphURL, user=graphUser, password=graphPassphrase)
```

I receive the following errors on trying to use this code.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ab3844caf22c> in <module>()
      3 graphPassphrase = "XXXX"
      4 
----> 5 graph=Graph(graphURL, user=graphUser, password=graphPassphrase)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in __new__(cls, *uris, **settings)
    333     def __new__(cls, *uris, **settings):
    334         database = settings.pop("database", "data")
--> 335         graph_service = GraphService(*uris, **settings)
    336         address = graph_service.address
    337         if database in graph_service:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\graph.py in __new__(cls, *uris, **settings)
     77         from py2neo.addressing import register_graph_service, get_graph_service_auth
     78         from py2neo.http import register_http_driver
---> 79         from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
     80         register_http_driver()
     81         address = register_graph_service(*uris, **settings)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 from .api import *
---> 22 from .bolt import *
     23 from .security import *
     24 from .types import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\bolt.py in <module>()
     30 from .security import SecurityPlan, Unauthorized
     31 from .summary import ResultSummary
---> 32 from .types import Record
     33 
     34 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\types\__init__.py in <module>()
     31 from operator import xor as xor_operator
     32 
---> 33 from neo4j.packstream import Structure
     34 from neo4j.compat import map_type, string, integer, ustr
     35 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neo4j\packstream\__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 from neo4j.util import import_best as _import_best
     23 
     24 from .structure import Structure

ImportError: cannot import name 'import_best'
```

I have tried using the handbook https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html?highlight=relation for v3 but it was of no use for my problem. Could you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The driver support the `BOLT` and `HTTP` proctole, but it seems here that you want to use the `HTTP` one, and the driver is trying to instantiate the `BOLT` ...

I recommend you to use `BOLT`, so your code should be :

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graphHost='localhost'
graphUser = "neo4j"
graphPassphrase = "XXXX"

graph=Graph(bolt=true, host=graphHost, user=graphUser, password=graphPassphrase)
```

If you really want to use the http :

```
  graph=Graph(bolt=false, host=graphHost, user=graphUser, password=graphPassphrase)
```